# Resource validation firing incorrectly

Tags: apex, trigger, validation

I have 2 resources, Vector Unit and Demo Unit. I am creating an event with these `Resources` which is the standard `Public Calendars and Resources`. I am putting all the resources and its Ids in a Custom Setting and querying it and adding it as an invitee to an event.

If a Resource is already allocated for an event happening on a particular day and the same resource is allocated to another event on the same day, a validation fires.

Now, if I change the resource say the Vector Unit to another unit, the validation is still firing saying that the Resource is allocated.

I looked at the debug log and the invitee is the new Vector Unit which does not have any events clashing with the current event.

I have given my code below. Where am I going wrong?

```
for(Resources__c res : [select Name, ID__c from Resources__c FOR UPDATE]){
         resourceMap.put(res.Name,res);
}

if(demo.Assigned_Vector_Unit_Number__c != NULL && !resourceMap.isEmpty() && resourceMap.containskey('Vector - '+demo.Assigned_Vector_Unit_Number__c) && resourceMap.get('Vector - '+demo.Assigned_Vector_Unit_Number__c) != NULL){
                      EventRelation er3 = new EventRelation(EventId = e.id,
                      RelationId = resourceMap.get('Vector - '+demo.Assigned_Vector_Unit_Number__c).Id__c, Status = 'Accepted');                        //Vector Unit is assigned to the Event
                      eventRelationList.add(er3);

}
if(demo.Assigned_Demo_Unit_Number__c != NULL && !resourceMap.isEmpty() && resourceMap.containskey('Demo - '+demo.Assigned_Demo_Unit_Number__c) && resourceMap.get('Demo - '+demo.Assigned_Demo_Unit_Number__c) != NULL){
                          EventRelation er4 = new EventRelation(EventId = e.id,
                          RelationId = resourceMap.get('Demo - '+demo.Assigned_Demo_Unit_Number__c).Id__c, Status = 'Accepted');                        //Demo Unit is assigned to the Event
                          eventRelationList.add(er4);
}

if(!eventRelationList.isEmpty()){
              system.debug('*********eventRelationList***********'+eventRelationList);
              system.debug('*********eventList***********'+eventList);
              try{
                  insert eventRelationList;  // The sales, Demo operator and the Logistics Manager is invited to the Demo Event
              }catch(exception e){

                  delete eventList;
                  for(Demo_Form__c Demo : newList){
                      demo.addError('One of the Resources has already been assigned! Kindly check the Salesforce Calendar and contact the Demo Manager');
                      eventRelationList.clear();
                  }
             }
}
```

Comment: Assuming the 'One of the Resources has already been assigned...' error message is appearing, I suggest you (temporarily) append the exception (just add `+ e` to the end of the message string) to see if that provides any more information.